# Can for loop be used as part of a function variable in Python?

Tags: python, generator-expression

I encountered a line of python code like this:

```
''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for _ in range(8))
```

It's kind of confusing.. anyone know what it does?

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/

Comment: It's a generator expression. There are also list, dict and set comprehensions with a similar syntax.

Comment: Side-note: In modern Python, the generator expression isn't necessary, because `random` spawned a `choices` (plural) method. So you could just write `''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits, k=8))` (which would also save repeatedly concatenating `ascii_lowercase` and `digits`).

Comment: What part specifically is the issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2):

> `''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for _ in range(8))`

When you see an expression like this, the best is to take it apart, step by step.

- `''` is an empty string
- `.join(...)` will join all characters (the ... part) and add it to the empty string
- `random.choice(...)` will choose any character at random
- `string.ascii_lower + string_digits` creates a string that contains all lower case characters and all digits
- `for _ in range(8)` means this is done 8 times (technically, this is a generator expression)

As a result, the whole expression returns a random string of 8 characters, all lower case or digits.

To learn more about generator expressions, [Dan Bader has a nice tutorial](https://dbader.org/blog/python-generator-expressions). If you're wondering how one comes up with an expression like this, the best is to study the Python documentation, [the official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this piece of code:

```
import random
import string

a = 'abcdefghijk'
print(a.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for _ in range(8)))
```

It gave me this output:

```
tabcdefghijk2abcdefghijk7abcdefghijktabcdefghijklabcdefghijkoabcdefghijkfabcdefghijk0
```

I believe it takes an input string and sticks it together 7 times with either a random lowercase letter or a random digit. (7 times because there is one on either end and there are therefore 8 joining digits).

Comment: Why are you using `a.join` instead of `''.join` as in the question?

Comment: Sorry... thought that the '' was a quotation mark around the .join, as that was before it was edited and it was less obvious. In the end I feel it makes it mildly more clear what the .join function is actually doing.